# Excel XY Chart: VBA Add Data Labels to Dynamic Selected Points

Tags: excel, vba, charts, label

I have XY Chart plotted based on column C & D values. I want to add data label to selected points in chart using values in column B. I wrote the code below, but Rn-Time error message pop-up all the time... It says "Method 'DataLabel' of Object 'Point' failed".

```
Sub AddLabelsToSelected()

Dim Cht As Chart
Dim i, ptcnt, ptindx, rownum As Integer

Set Cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

' Add labels to these many selected points
ptcnt = Range("A1").Value

For i = 1 To ptcnt

ptindx = Cells(i + 29, 1).Value
rownum = Cells(i + 29, 1).Value + 29

    Cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(ptindx).DataLabel.Text = _
      ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 2).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if you call `Cht.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels` first, before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

ptindx is becoming an invalid value for Points() to use...
In turn, Points(ptindx).DataLabels refers to something that either doesn't exist, or can't be associated with a datalabel.

Or, perhaps you have to make the datalabel visible first.
i.e.  `.Points(ptindx).HasDataLabel = TRUE`